# Count "changes in direction" in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I need to count how many times a variable inverts its growth pattern - from increasing values to decreasing values (as well as from decreasing values to increasing values). In the following example, I should be able to find 4 such inversions. How can I create a new dummy variable that shows such inversions?

```
x <- c(1:20,19:5,6:15,12:9,10:11)
plot(x)
```

[image: A vector with 4 "change in direction"]

Answer (score 2):

You're effectively asking "when is the second derivative of x not equal to zero?", so you could just do a double diff:

```
x <- c(1:20,19:5,6:15,12:9,10:11)
plot(seq_along(x), x)
changes <- c(0, diff(diff(x)), 0) != 0
```

To show it picks the right points, colour them red.

```
points(seq_along(x)[changes], x[changes], col = "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the indices at which the direction changed:

```
get_change_indices <- function(x){
  # return 0 if x contains one (or none, if NULL) unique elements
  if(length(unique(x)) <= 1) return(NULL)

  # make x named, so we can recapture its indices later
  x <- setNames(x, paste0("a", seq_along(x)))

  # calculate diff between successive elements
  diff_x <- diff(x)

  # remove points that are equal to zero
  diff_x <- diff_x[!diff_x==0]

  # identify indices of changepoints
  diff_x <- c(diff_x[1], diff_x)
  change_ind <- NULL
  for(i in 2:length(diff_x)){
    if(sign(diff_x[i]) != sign(diff_x[i-1])){
      change_ind_curr <- as.numeric(gsub("a", "", names(diff_x[i]))) - 1
      change_ind <- c(change_ind, change_ind_curr)
    } 
  }

  change_ind
}
```

The length of its output is the number of changes.

Note that it also works when the change in `x` is non-linear, e.g. if `x <- c(1, 4, 9, 1)`.